# Css Media queries using with current div style

Tags: css, media-queries

Can I use Media queries with current div style maybe like that:

```
.myDiv {
  anyStyle : ...;

  @media (myDiv's width > 100px) {
    height: 40px;
  }

}
```

I found several pages,but there said only using window params.
if anybody know how to use the media, please tell me about 
I saw the links:

1. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
3. http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: Actually, your question is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please, explain what is your point here. I mean what are you trying to achieve, really.

Comment: in my case div depends on div's scale, and scale does not relate to window width

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the `height` of the `.myDiv` relatively to its `width`?

Comment: I don't get it. The div stays with the same width, right? Then what did you mean by _scale_ in your previous comment?

Comment: Can you not simply set the height constant too? The scale is applied only after the width/height is set, so what is the point in finding out what the width is after the transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it that way:

```css
.myDiv {
    /* your styles */
}

@media only screen (min-width: 100px) {
    .myDiv {
        /* other styles */
    }
}
```

The **only** way to work with media queries is to rely on device type (*screen*, *print* etc.) and/or device width (*min-width*, *max-width*).

Comment: does `min-width` mean `myDiv.width' ?

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich no. It means window width.

Comment: realy, is there no way how to make it

Answer (score 4):

No.

You can't use media queries to check the width of an item on your website. Media queries only check the viewport variables like width and height. You should use them to check what kind of screen your user has and not what style you have applied to your div.